# Изменить requestSuffix и responseSuffix для DefaultWsdl11Definition

Tags: java, spring, xsd, wsdl

Здравствуйте. Суть вопроса: мне нужно с xsd генерить wsdl. Имею следующий xsd:

```
    <element name="requestStatusDelivery">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element minOccurs="0" name="msgIdExt" type="string" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    </element>

    <element name="responseStatusDelivery">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element minOccurs="0" name="msgIdExt" type="string"/>
                <element minOccurs="0" name="statusDelivery" type="string"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
```

**spring-ws-servlet:**

```
   <bean id="SMS" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
    <property name="schema">
        <bean id="xsd" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
            <property name="xsd" value="/WEB-INF/Sms.xsd"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="portTypeName" value="SMS"/>
    <property name="locationUri" value="http://localhost:8080/SMS"/>
   </bean>
```

Если все так и оставить, то в wsdl не будут созданы `<wsdl:operation></wsdl:operation>`. Но если в xsd прописать вместо requestStatusDelivery - statusDeliveryRequest, а вместо responseStatusDelivery - statusDeliveryResponse, то все будет сгенерированно как надо. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно **проигнорировать дефолтные суффиксы** или прописать префиксы?

---

Я могу прописать пропертя для этого бина и для данного примера все будет работать хорошо

```
    <property name="requestSuffix" value="StatusDelivery" />
    <property name="responseSuffix" value="StatusDelivery" />
```

Но, допустим в одном xsd есть несколько таких request и response методов. Тогда пропертя уже не помогут. Хотелось бы прописать полное игнорирование суффиксов глобально, для всех бинов.

Answer (score 0):

Это возможно, нужно реализовать свой Wsdl11Defifnition. Вам нужно будет переопределить 3 файла: SuffixBasedMessagesProvider, SuffixBasedPortTypesProvider и сам Wsdl11Definition. Подобными вещами тоже приходилось заниматься из-за именования методов в сервисе. Пример реализации с пустым суффиксом: [Custom Wsdl11Definition](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/n0c1ip/77gRe/custom-wsdl11definition-for-spring-ws)
. Код там не сложный, можно очень гибко настроить сервис.